# "far from" versus "away from"

Tags: meaning, word-choice

What word should be used when referring to a metaphorical state of two concepts that do not relate to each other?

For example: Love is far from hate, Art is far from commercial interests, Artists who are far from the majoritarian habits?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by *far from*. You mention *unrelated*, for instance, which is quite different from *opposite* (and there can be different senses of opposition or difference). Love is certainly not unrelated to hate, for instance. As it stands now, the question should be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 2):

*[Poles apart](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/poles+apart)*:

> very different; far from coming to an agreement. (Alludes to the
>   distance between the north and south poles. 
>   Typically: be ~; become ~; grow ~.)
>
> Mr. and Mrs. Jones don't get along well. They are poles apart. They'll
>   never sign the contract because they are poles apart.
>
> *McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs. © 2002*

- *Love and hate are poles apart.*
- *Art and commercial interests are poles apart.*
- *Artists and the majoritarian habits are poles apart.*

---

Using the same word picture ***polar opposite***:

- *Love is the polar opposite of hate.*
- *Art is the polar opposite of commercial interests.*
- *Artists are the polar opposite of the majoritarian habits.*

Answer (score 1):

How about "magnitude"? As in "loving someone is a magnitude greater than liking them."

Answer (score 0):

You could say that one is the **antithesis** of the other.

> **Antithesis:**
>
> : the exact opposite of something or someone
>
> : the state of two things that are directly opposite to each other
>
> ([Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/antithesis))

Love is the antithesis of hate, slavery is the antithesis of freedom, etc.

Comment: Thank you! it's not exactly the same to be the antithesis of than to be far from something.. (though all the examples were antithetical concepts). I am looking for a word to use when you feel the concepts could have certain relationship... a distant one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have

***non-congruent***

in logic. It might be too hard for poetry, but ...

> **congruent**
>
> 1
>
> b [logic] :  relating to or predicable of the same subject :
> differing from each other but predicable as true of the same state of
> things
>
> *congruent propositions*
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

Also, perhaps more ameanable to poetry commentary:

*they are **things of different /worlds/spheres/***

> Pagan Fire - Page 55 Norval Richardson - 1920 - ‎Snippet view - ‎More
> editions
>
> They were totally unlike, were interested in **things of different
> worlds**,
>
> -
>
> The Intellectual repository for the New Church. ... - Page 86
>
> New Church gen. confer - 1864 - ‎Read - ‎More editions It is the
> effort to commingle **things of different spheres**, and can only
> result in confusion.

Answer (score 0):

*[Contrary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/contrary)*:

> adjective
>
> 1 Opposite in nature, direction, or meaning:
>   *ODO*

- *Love is contrary to hate.*
- *Art is contrary to commercial interests.*
- *Artists are contrary to the majoritarian habits?*

Comment: Thank you! it's not exactly the same to be contrary to than to be far from something.. (though all the  examples were contradictory concepts). It might be a word to use when you feel the concepts could have certain relationship... a distant one.

Comment: Agreed. @user116664, the actual relationship between the pairs is not "unrelated" and defining the nature of those relationships is a matter of nuance.